# summation function in java

Tags: java, sum

I am getting strange behavior with this basic piece of java code

```
  public class Sigma {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           int sum = sigma(3);
           System.out.println(sum);
       }

       public static int sigma(int n){
           int sum = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
               sum += 1;
           }
           return sum;
       }
   }
```

The expected output is `6`, however when I run the code I get `4`

Comment: please first use debugger tools in such situations!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is wrong, you should change `sum += 1;` to  `sum += i;`

And if you are doing an AP summation from 1 to N better use directly the formula:

> (n*(n+1))/2

Comment: for anyone seeing this later, a more general AP formula: `Sum = n(2*first_term + (n-1)(difference))/2`

Comment: @sushain97 10x for this info.I should have added this well before.

Comment: feel free to edit and add to your answer for increased visibility

Comment: Thank you for this equation! I knew there was a mathematical way to represent summation without a `for` loop, but string manipulation is my specialty.

Comment: @sushain97 What's the difference between your algorithm and the one in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

You should change the code as `sum+=1` to `sum+=i;`